# Selecting linked list from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table looking like this:

```
> describe books;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| after         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, I want to select all rows from the table, but as sorted linked list. `after` is an `id` of row it should be after in query result. Of course I could do that after query in my script using this table, but I'd like to know if there is a way to get the rows sorted in such way.

Example of data in table:

```
(1, "title #1", 0)
(2, "title #2", 3)
(3, "title #3", 1)
(4, "title #4", 2)
```

Expected result:

```
(1, "title #1", 0)
(3, "title #3", 1)
(2, "title #2", 3)
(4, "title #4", 2)
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Do you want to order based on the 'after' field? Just do: `Order by after`

Comment: I've added a 4th row to show why `ORDER BY after` won't work. I'm afraid this can't be easily done.

Comment: @Tim, no, of course not. It's list of books to be put chronologically, but it should be possible to add a book between #1 and #2 (say, it would be #3), so I could just iterate through the result and get them in this order: #1, #3, #2.

Comment: @Thirler, hmm, thanks, I guess it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: why would anyone downvote this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for all rows, your `after` values are smaller (or all larger) than your `id` values, the posted `ORDER BY` solution will do.

If not, you will need to traverse the after->id relation iteratively, and the original SQL does not support this at all. Modern SQLs do allow you to do this within a `SELECT` clause, e.g. Oracle has `CONNECT BY`, and [recursive subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668860/standard-alternative-to-connect-by) will do the trick as well. MySQL doesn't apparently have an equivalent.

An alternative is to do the iteration in [the procedural language you can wrap around SQL queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html), like in [the article Skrol29 links to](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

However, this iteration, regardless of how you perform it, will always be slow.

Another approach is to redesign the way in which you are representing this relationship in the database - see e.g. the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this standard in mysql you could write something like

```
Select * from books b_root
   Left join books as b_child1 ON b_root.after = b_child1.id
      Left join books as b_child2 ON b_child1.after = b_child2.id
Where b_root.after = 0
```

You will get something like 
(1, "title #1", 0,3, "title #3", 1,2, "title #2", 3)

thats 3 deep
or try linking it in a script or programming language

Example of a python script that solves this problem

```
books = [
{'id':1, 'title' :"title #1", 'after':0},
{'id':2, 'title' :"title #2", 'after':3},
{'id':3, 'title' :"title #3", 'after':1},
{'id':4, 'title' :"title #4", 'after':2},]

def recursive(book):
    global books

    for i in books:
        if book['id'] == i['after']:

            print i
            recursive(i)

for i in books:
        if i['after'] == 0:
            print i
            recursive(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY after;
```

does not work. The problem as described is like a queue of persons, where everyone just knows the single person directly ahead.

IMHO the best approach is to have a separate sorting table representing the queue:

```
> describe books_order;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| order_no      | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |
| books_id      | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+

SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = (SELECT books_id FROM books_order ORDER BY order_no);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a hierarchical query problem.
Your need is in fact to sort the rows considering that each row has for parent the row with "child_row.after=parent_row.id".

If your hierarchy has only one level, it can be done with a simple query.
If your hierarchy has a free number of level, then it is quite difficult the solve it since MySQL doesn't has hierarchical features.

But here is an article to solve the problem:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Having this table:

```
create table list(id int primary key not null, previous int, description varchar(10));
```

You can obtain elements by:

```
select l2.* from (select @r as _parent, @r := (select id from list where previous = _parent) as id, @n := @n + 1 as n from (select @r := 0, @n := 0) vars, list) k, list l2 where k.id = l2.id order by n;
```

Answer (score -3):

This should give you the expected result.

```
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY after;
```

Visit the following link for more details:
[Mysql Select Tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: This was the answer to the user first question which was edited and redesigned.

Comment: just huge lol. I don't know if you know that, but everyone can check the revision history of my post and see that there was just a row added to the example.

Comment: (1, "title #1", 0)
    (3, "title #3", 1)
    (2, "title #2", 3)

vs 

(1, "title #1", 0)
(3, "title #3", 1)
(2, "title #2", 3)
(4, "title #4", 2)

Comment: **Last time, I am not going to go into flame war with you anywhere further: the essence of the question is the question**, where the problem is explained, not the example, that wasn't exactly as it should've been, but you should first read the question, then example, not the other way around.